# How do I get the text of a tag

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to grab the text of the  that was clicked. I have a case where two different links are defined under teh same class and I need to identify which of the links was clicked

```
<div class="block pdp-estimate-quote">
  <ul>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Estimate Payment</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Get a Quote</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

And I want to throw a GA event when someone clicks either link using the link text as the description. The following code throws an event but it shows the text for both links instead of just the one that was clicked.

```
$('.pdp-estimate-quote a').click(function(){ 
    var ctatext = $(this).closest(".pdp-estimate-quote").find('a').text();
    dataLayer.push({ 'event':'event', 'eventCategory': 'Get Quote', 'eventAction':ctatext, 'eventLabel':{{url path}}  }) 
});
```

Comment: Couldn't you just use `$(this).text()`?

Answer (score 5):

I might be missing something on your question but in order to get the text of the current element you just need to do

```
var ctatext = $(this).text();
```

So the complete function would be

```
$('.pdp-estimate-quote a').click(function(){ 
    var ctatext = $(this).text();
    dataLayer.push({ 'event':'event', 'eventCategory': 'Get Quote', 'eventAction':ctatext, 'eventLabel':{{url path}}  }) 
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Because you are looking at the parent element and not the clicked element.

```
var ctatext = $(this).closest(".pdp-estimate-quote").find('a').text();
```

should be

```
var ctatext = $(this).text();
```

Comment: *"Because you are looking at the parent element"* not exactly, though the solution is still correct.

Comment: well, he's actually looking at a cousin element, hence the `.find('a')`

Answer (score 1):

In event handlers, `this` refers to the element on which the event was fired. So in a click handler, `this` is the DOM element that was clicked.

```
var ctatext = $(this).text();
```